# How can I make an array that contains all the roles a person has? (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

For one of my Discord bots, I need an array that contains all the roles a person has. Is there any way to do this? I am using discord.js

Comment: the [`member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) object has a roles property. That should server you well.

Answer (score 0):

From the [official docs on `GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=roles):

> `.roles`
> A manager for the roles belonging to this member.
>
> Type: [`GuildMemberRoleManager`](https://discord.js.org#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager)

Looking at [`GuildMemberRoleManager`](https://discord.js.org#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager), we see a very interesting property:

> `.cache`
> The roles of this member.
>
> Type: `Collection<Snowflake, Role>`

However, we don't want a `Collection`, we want an array, so we can reference the [docs for collection](https://discord.js.org#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=array), which reveals an `array` method that returns an array of the values. So, the final code is:

```js
const roles = member.roles.cache.array();
```